# accessing files from an FTP site in android

Tags: android, ftp

What I want to achieve in my application is:

I have an account on ftp site like "filegenie.com" where i store some images.
Now I want to view those images when i start my application.

How can I do this in android? Can any one give me an head start into how those files should be accessed from the ftp site?  I actually have no idea in this section. some simple tutorials, hints, examples are welcome.

My sole objective is to view images stored on filegenie.com from my android application

Answer (score 0):

I have to do something similar with an FTP server I run off a destop. I downloaded a couple helper classes that are quite simple to use: [FTP Classes Site](http://androiddevblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/android-ftp-client.html)

If you are using the android eclipse plugin open windows explorer and copy the jars into the "libs" folder in your project.

Here is a snipet of the type of code you would need:

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

try {
    ftpClient.connect(my.ip.com,port);
    ftpClient.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(PATH);

    if (ftpClient.getReplyString().contains("250")) {
        ftpClient.setFileType(org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        BufferedInputStream buffIn = null;
        buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(FULL_PATH_TO_LOCAL_FILE));
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        boolean result = ftpClient.storeFile(FILENAME, buffIn);
        buffIn.close();
        ftpClient.logout();
        ftpClient.disconnect();
    }

} catch (SocketException e) {
    System.err.print...
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    System.err.print...
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.print...
}

if(!result)
    {.....}
```

Feel free to look through the [FTPClient library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.2/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#storeFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream%29)

Comment: 06-05 12:14:49.120: E/AndroidRuntime(10177): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient

Comment: did u build apache jar file